# Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' - Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic5

I'm using vue on Ionic and have my code like this :

```
data() {
    return {
      events: []
   };
},
```

The template :

```
<CardEvent
        v-for="event of events"
        :key="event.event_ID"
        @click="router.push(`/home/evenement/` + event.event_ID)"
        button
        :title="event.event_title"
        :picture="event.event_picture"
        :addressExists="event.address_exists"
        :day="event.event_day"
        :month="event.event_month"
        :isVirtual="event.is_virtual"
      />
```

I have a method to push to my events array :

```
loadMore() {
  //Data here
  this.events.push(response.data);  // => error here
},
```

On this line I got the error "`Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'`"

I saw that we can do something like : `const result : string[] = [];`  but how to achieve this with the data object ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define your data property as `Array<any>`

```
events: [] as Array<any>
```

but it's recommended to type the `response.data` and the `events` like:

```
events: [] as Array<SomeEventType>
```